# How to Create New Column Based on Another Column With Missing Value in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, nan

My question is described in the following video link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nk5tBosK0iU

I don't know why I cannot get the condition (`df[condition]`), where `condition` is a variable, worked for NaN values.

Comment: just another side question ... how can I post link on Stackoverflow that can be opened in new browser window?

Comment: It is interesting to note that you could make a video with your question, but not google an answer for it, or for that matter type it out here... I am sorry, I cannot make a video response to that.

Comment: Thanks Kartik ...I googled the answer (tried the np.where, lambda apply method) before I shot the question video ...  I also tried to type (and paste) my code (and result) from iPython Notebook ...but still couldn't get the format right (would like to learn how to get the correct table format on Stackoverflow though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need check scalar `NaN` in custom function by [`pandas.isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html), but faster solution is with double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'CloseDelta':[np.nan,-0.5,0.5],
                   'B':[0,1,0]})

print (df)
  B  CloseDelta
0  0         NaN
1  1        -0.5
2  0         0.5

def f(x):
    if (pd.isnull(x)):
        return 0
    elif (x<0):
        return -1 
    else: 
        return 1

df['new'] = np.where(df.CloseDelta.isnull(), 0, np.where(df.CloseDelta<0, -1, 1))

df['new1'] = df.CloseDelta.apply(f)

print (df)
   B  CloseDelta  new  new1
0  0         NaN    0     0
1  1        -0.5   -1    -1
2  0         0.5    1     1
```

**Timings**:

```
#[300000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [28]: %timeit np.where(df.CloseDelta.isnull(), 0, np.where(df.CloseDelta<0, -1, 1))
100 loops, best of 3: 1.99 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit df.CloseDelta.apply(f)
1 loop, best of 3: 245 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael ... let me try ...
Let's see if my new column, df.['New']  = df.['CloseDelta'].apply(function) works ... :)

Comment: thanks very much jezrael ...
just included what you did (with your name quoted) in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQuerSKl1as